# How to call another function that utilizes argc, char *argv[] in main without passing things to it?

Tags: c

say there is a function in my code:
`int getwords(int argc, char *argv[])`
and I want to call this function in main().
How do I call this in main without erroring out?

```
`void main(void)
    getwords();`
```

Comment: you pass argc and argv to it

Comment: `int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) { getwords(argc, argv); }` Failing that there might (or might not) be a platform specific way of getting to those values, but why create a platform specific complication, when you can do it simply?

Comment: In standard C, `main()` must return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: @AviBerger The problem is I have to call everything from main, all other functions can do things, main can only call functions.

Comment: I don't follow, @DakotaKellogg.  How does Avi's suggested `main()` do anything other than call functions?

Comment: In any case, you describe `getwords()` as a function that takes arguments.  Such a function must be called with the appropriate arguments, else the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Also the names `argc` and `argv` are just conventional.  There is no special behavior associated with those names themselves.  The arguments to `main()` can be and sometimes are named differently.  Using those names for other functions' parameters does not trigger any special behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `main` to provide access to `argc` and `argv`:

```
int main(int argv, char **argv) {
  // ...
}
```

Then you can pass those to another function when you call it:

```
void foo(int argc, char **argv) {
  // ...
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  foo(argc, argv);
}
```

`argc` will be copied, but `argv` is a pointer, so the *pointer* is copied
but not the data it *points to*.

Answer (score 0):

if for some special reason you do not want to use parameters you can use global variables available in all program.

```
int gargc;
char **gargv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gargc = argc;
    gargv = argv;

    getopt();
}
```